# How do I attach leads to a SOT-227B/miniBLOC package?

Tags: power-electronics, bridge-rectifier, packages

I am reviewing options for full-wave rectifiers for a several thousand watt project, and many of the options are in the SOT-227B/miniBLOC package.  I am not familiar with this package, and when I was reviewing its mounting guidelines, it was unclear how external connections are intended to be connected to the package.

Here is an example of the SOT-227B package:

[image: Here is an example of the SOT-227B package]

Do incoming leads go on top of or under the copper terminal tabs?  I have found plenty of information in the application notes about mounting the base plate for best thermal contact, but the guidelines for the terminals reference the tightening torque only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use ring terminals. They go on top, not under the tab. Or at least I put them on top. It never looked like they would go under the tab to me.

Comment: On top makes the most sense to me the more I think about it.  The [Microsemi mounting guide](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/125317-mounting-considerations-for-the-sot-227-package) describes the terminal as having a "U-bend for stress relief".  With a ring connector underneath the tab, tightening the screw could result in a pulling strain, which does not seem desirable.

Comment: @JonathanMoore It actually won't cause strain because the nut sits freely in its fitted hex hole and is only held captive the tab overhead. So tightening the screw just lifts the nut out of its hole. No stress is placed on the tab.

Comment: That helps a lot to understand how it is assembled!  I have not handled any components in this package before.

Comment: +1 Yes, the M4 ring terminal goes on top, screw to recommended torque. It's also possible to screw the part onto a PCB or  bus bars.

Comment: @JonathanMoore If you tighten too hard the nut breaks the plastic and falls out of its hole. It's a pain to put it under the tab anyways...you only have one direction from which the terminal can approach. With the terminal on top you have 90 degrees of approach angle.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/23D8hqU.png

Comment: use a slim crescent wrench to hold the nut during tightening